# Problem with ubuntu 12.04 login

Tags: 12.04, installation, login, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

just need some quick help. I looked at some websites and watched a couple of vids and decided to completely switch to This OS. I did an install from windows 7 to this OS version 12.04 through USB. The installation goes smooth. The problem is after installation though. Whenever I login it freezes on me. It just shows the default wallpaper and nothing really happens. I've re-installed about 3 times now and the same problem occurs. Hopefully there's a way to solve this quickly. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to ubuntu 2d at login and see if things load in. I had to do that with a dell e521.

Comment: Sorry in my case it definitely was the ubuntu 3d default. After login it had same symptom of only loading wallpaper and having nothing else really working. The graphics was overloading or something.